# query to fetch the key based on est code or fetch default estcode value

Tags: sql, oracle, jpql

```
  +----+--------------+-----------+--------------++--------------+
| ID | KEY          | CODE      |    VALUE     |     ACTIVE    |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 1  | MIN_VAL_EMP  | 111       |    100       |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 2  | MIN_VAL_MARR | 222       |    110       |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 3  | MIN_VAL_FOOD | 0         |    10        |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 4  | MAX_VAL_EMP  | 121       |    8000      |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 5  | MAX_VAL_MARR | 0         |    20        |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 6  | MAX_VAL_FOOD | 0         |    30        |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| 7  | MIN_VAL_EMP  | 0         |    80        |       Y       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Need to write a query,

If my CODE value is present then fetch that, if not present fetch those KEY  with CODE is 0.
Also, there should not be duplicate KEY in the result, either the KEY with CODE or with the default CODE(0). Both will not be present.
Have to take care that, all these rules are applied only to record's ACTIVE = Y

For example if my CODE is 111.

The result will be,

```
+----+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| ID | KEY          | CODE      |    VALUE     |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | MIN_VAL_EMP  | 111       |    100       |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| 3  | MIN_VAL_FOOD | 0         |    10        |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| 5  | MAX_VAL_MARR | 0         |    20        |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| 6  | MAX_VAL_FOOD | 0         |    30        |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Here, below row will not be part of the result, since we KEY with CODE 111 is present.

```
| 7  | MIN_VAL_EMP  | 0         |    80        |
```

Comment: what do you mean for "est" code?

Comment: question modified

Answer (score 1):

You can use a where in

```
select distinct id, key, code, value
frm my_table 
where (key,code) in (select key, max(code) 
                    from my_table where code = 111 or code = 0 
                    group by key)
```

Comment: Can we add active condition also in this ? These rules are applied only to records that are active

Comment: @user630209   please explain better  whta do you need -

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, KEY, CODE, VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT ID, KEY, CODE, VALUE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KEY 
                            ORDER BY CASE 
                                        WHEN KEY = 111 THEN 1
                                        ELSE 2
                                     END) rn
  FROM mytable
  WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND CODE IN (111, 0)) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.id, t.key,t.code, t.value from table t
where t.code= 111 and t.active = 'y'
union
select t.id, t.key,t.code, t.value from table t
where t.code= 0 and t.key not in 
(
  select t.key from table t
  where t.code= 111 and t.active = 'y'
)
```

This should work